# how to handle manual clearing in google.maps.places. API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google.maps.places.API to provide a location search to the user. 
When the user types and selects a location, I am catching the <strike>location</strike> coordinates in a variable(center hidden element) and using it for processing. However when the user is not satisfied, they may want to blank out the location input element manually and try to search by other options. In this case I want to clear of the <strike>lat and lng variables</strike> location input and thus the center input element values. I have tried to capture the onBlur event of the location search box, but not able to clear <strike>these variables</strike> it.

```
<script>
    var autocomplete;
function initialize() {
    var input = (document.getElementById('location'));
    var options = {
      types: ['(cities)']
    };
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}
function fillInAddress() {
   // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.  
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   var val = place.geometry.location;
  document.getElementById('center').value = val;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Please advice how do I clear of the input element location( and thus element center ). Or am I missing a vital point in the code.

Comment: there are no lat/lng-variables in your code.

Comment: The element 'center'(hidden in html) gets the lat, lng for example (38.58, -121.49). I am splitting it later in php into two variables lat, lng. The issue is how do I clear 'location' and thus 'center' if the user manually clears the location box..Sorry for the error in phrasing the question.

Comment: set the value of the center-box to an empty string when the value of the location-box is an empty string.

Comment: Yes Sir, that worked. I added the code on onSubmit. Sometimes the solution is right in front of you and you just miss it. Thanks for your help.